# Compare the current row against subsequent rows (order by date and group) in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I have dataset that contains 3 columns (Group, Date, Value). For each row (combination of Group and Date), I would like to evaluate when (in days) does the value increase by 1%.

```
df <- read.table(text =
                    "Group   Date    value
                  A      11/1/17     56
                  A      11/2/17     51
                  A      11/3/17     58
                  A      11/4/17     62
                  A      11/5/17     60
                  A      11/6/17     55
                  A      11/7/17     56
                  A      11/8/17     56
                  A      11/9/17     53
                  B      11/1/17     56
                  B      11/2/17     63
                  B      11/3/17     50
                  B      11/4/17     62
                  B      11/5/17     65
                  B      11/6/17     61
                  B      11/7/17     56
                  B      11/8/17     62 
                  C      11/1/17     50
                  C      11/2/17     62 ", header = T)
```

I would like the output to look something like this…  I am interested in the column `increase_by_1%`. **The `increase_by_1%` is a date difference between when the current row increases by 1%. So, the date that value increased minus the date of the current value.**

For example, the logic for the 1st row would be

```
# if group == A & (value on 11/2/17 = 51 –  value on 11/1/17 = 56)/ value on 11/1/17 = 56 >= .01 THEN FALSE  
# if group == A &  (value on 11/3/17 = 58 –  value on 11/1/17 = 56)/ value on 11/1/17 = 56 >= .01 = TRUE THEN (**11/3/17 - 11/1/17 = 2**)
```

The logic for the 2nd row...

```
# if group == A & (value on 11/3/17 = 58 –  value on 11/2/17 = 51)/ value on 11/2/17 = 51 >= .01 = TRUE THEN (**11/3/17 - 11/2/17 = 1**)
```

the logic for the 4th row...

```
# if group == A & (value on 11/5/17 = 60 –  value on 11/4/17 = 62)/ value on 11/4/17 = 62 >= .01 = FALSE THEN NA

# if group == A & (value on 11/6/17 = 55 –  value on 11/4/17 = 62)/ value on 11/4/17 = 62 >= .01 = FALSE THEN NA

# if group == A & (value on 11/7/17 = 56 –  value on 11/4/17 = 62)/ value on 11/4/17 = 62 >= .01 = FALSE THEN NA

# if group == A & (value on 11/8/17 = 56 –  value on 11/4/17 = 62)/ value on 11/4/17 = 62 >= .01 = FALSE THEN NA

# if group == A & (value on 11/9/17 = 53 –  value on 11/4/17 = 62)/ value on 11/4/17 = 62 >= .01 = FALSE THEN NA
```

NA means that the current row (e.g., 11/4/17) value does not increase for subsequent rows.

---

```
+=======+=========+=======+================+
| Group |  Date   | value | increase_by_1% |
+=======+=========+=======+================+
| A     | 11/1/17 |    56 | 2              | 
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| A     | 11/2/17 |    51 | 1              |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| A     | 11/3/17 |    58 | 1              |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| A     | 11/4/17 |    62 | NA             |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| A     | 11/5/17 |    60 | NA             |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| A     | 11/6/17 |    55 | 1              |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| A     | 11/7/17 |    56 | NA             |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| A     | 11/8/17 |    56 | NA             |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| A     | 11/9/17 |    53 | NA             |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| B     | 11/1/17 |    56 | 1              |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| B     | 11/2/17 |    63 | 3              |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| B     | 11/3/17 |    50 | 1              |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| B     | 11/4/17 |    62 | 1              |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| B     | 11/5/17 |    65 | NA             |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| B     | 11/6/17 |    61 | 2              |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| B     | 11/7/17 |    56 | 1              |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| B     | 11/8/17 |    62 | NA             |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| C     | 11/1/17 |    50 | 1              |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
| C     | 11/2/17 |    62 | NA             |
+-------+---------+-------+----------------+
```

This is what I have so far, however, this is not scalable. If there are more dates, then I would need to manually add those in the if else statement.

```
shift <- function(x, n){
  c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n))
}

df= do.call(rbind,by(df,df$Group, transform,next_1_percent_or_higher_change =
                        ifelse(((shift(value,1)-value)/value) >= .01,1,
                               ifelse(((shift(value,2)-value)/value) >= .01,2,
                               ifelse(((shift(value,3)-value)/value) >= .01,3,
                                      ifelse(((shift(value,4)-value)/value) >= .01,4,
                                             ifelse(((shift(value,5)-value)/value) >= .01,5,
                                                    ifelse(((shift(value,6)-value)/value) >= .01,6,
                                                            ifelse(((shift(value,7)-value)/value) >= .01,7,
                                                                  ifelse(((shift(value,8)-value)/value) >= .01,8,
                                                                         ifelse(((shift(value,9)-value)/value) >= .01,9,NA)))))))))))
```

Comment: The logic is not very clear. Can you please specify when it will be 1, 2 and NA? Why row 1 value is 2 and in row 5 value is NA?

Comment: Yes, the description is now revised. The logic is a date difference between the current row and the row that the value increases by 1% for each group. For example, for row 1 (Group A, 11/1/17, 56), the value increased by 1% on 11/3/17, which means it took 2 days to increase by 1% (or, 11/3/17 - 11/1/17 = 2).Whereas, for row 4 (Group A , 11/4/17, 60 ), the value of 60 does not increase in subsequent rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're looking for `value` changes of >1% over prior row, limited to within the same `Group`.

```
library(dplyr)

f_flagged_shorter <- f %>%
      group_by(Group) %>%
      mutate(flag = value >= lag(value)*1.01) %>%
      ungroup()
```

Comment: No, I am looking for **when** (duration in days) the `value` increases by 1%.  In my desired output, I want a new column called ` increase_by_1%`, which indicates when a value for each row and limited to a Group increase by 1%. For example, it took the first row (i.e., A , 11/1/17, 56 ) , 2 days to increase by 1%. It took the second row (A,11/2/17, 51), 1 day to increase by 1%.

Comment: Ok, maybe I understand now. Is this right?   For each date,  find the number of days that must elapse to get to the next date in the group where the value will have increased by 1% from the current level.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for